# WinRm between different versions

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0, winrm

If you Winrm (remote powershell session) from your local computer which runs psh 4.0 to a server that runs psh 2.0 will you still be able to run 4.0 commands on the  2.0 box?

Just trying to figure this out before I go thorugh the leg work of opening up the firewall and running `winrm autoconfig` on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, when you enter a remote pssession you only have access to the powershell version and modules located on the remote host.

Comment: That's a huge bummer, looks like I may have to update powershell somehow